# PHP: are classes in classes possible? static returns

Tags: php, class, static, constants

I am creating a constant mirror of my Database so i don't have problems with typo's anymore.

what i was hoping to achieve is to brouwse trough it in a folder like structure. like:

```
echo Db::categorie::id;  // should return Cat_ID
```

is this possible, or something simmilar? now it gives errors because it is not possible.
below the code:

```
class Db // database
{
    /*@var $categorie DbCatergorie*/
    const categorie = DbCatergorie;
}

class DbCatergorie // table in database
{
    Const id = "Cat_ID";
    Const name = "Cat_Name";
    Const imgId = "Cat_Img_ID";
    Const volgorde = "Cat_Volgorde";
}
```

thx
Matthy

Comment: class constants cannot be variables, properties, the results of a mathematical operation, or a function call... or classes. You'd be better off defining a static property.

Comment: Use static property and set in construct.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible.
Class constants must be a constant. Not even constant expressions are supported.

From [manual](http://bd.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php)

> The value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a property, a result of a mathematical operation, or a function call.

```
// Wrong!
class C{
    const c = 54*34;
}
```

If you are worried about typo, I suggest this,

```
class Db // database
{
    Const CAT_ID = "Cat_ID";
    Const CAT_NAME = "Cat_Name";
    Const CAT_IMG_ID = "Cat_Img_ID";
    Const CAT_VOLGORDE = "Cat_Volgorde";
}
```